# How to change properties of all buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a C# WPF project (VS 2010) having some buttons in various forms and want to set some common properties to all those buttons (e.g: bold text, change color on hover). However I can set  properties from Properties tab and hover behavior one by one using the following code.

```
private void btnOne_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.Orange;
}

 private void btnTwo_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {         
     (sender as Button).BackColor = Color.LightGray;
 }
```

Is there any way to change all buttons properties from a single place? Any example available?

Comment: you can write style for button in App.xaml and apply the style to all the buttons that you want to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF you can do it in XAML.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I can see App.config, but where is App.xaml?

Comment: The xaml file will be the 'designer' for the cs file you are making where you can drag+drop/edit properties of UI items. The xaml.cs file will be the partial class of the code behind that.

The App.xaml should be in your project next to your app.config and your xaml file. The App.xaml will let you define application resources for your program.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with WPF isn't fantastic but could you instead set the MouseHover and MouseLeave as an XAML style (I've wrote this from scratch not in an IDE as i'm on my phone so it may no be exactly right):

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="GRAY_COLOUR" />
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="ORANGE_COLOUR" />
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Replacing the `GRAY_COLOUR` and `ORANGE_COLOUR` with either the hex values for that colour or define them as static resources. Then assign that style to all applicable buttons:

`<Button Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />`